# An optimal procedure for vertex elimination in a graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, coloring

[Figure: An example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXx4A.jpg)
[image]
Hi everyone. I'm struggling with a problem, and I really appreciate any hint.
I have attached picture of an example where vertex 1 and 2 are connected to multiple vertices (green circles and blue squares). I want to gradually eliminate some of these blue and green vertices such that the number of edges connected to vertex 1 or 2 does not exceed 4. Also, my objective is doing this with the minimum number of eliminations. So, let's define it mathematically. If $d_B$ and $d_G$ respectively denote the number of remaining blue squares and green circles after elimination, and also if $d_i$ denotes the connected edges to vertex $i$ after elimination,  my problem is how to organize an optimal elimination procedure such that it maximizes $min(d_B,d_G)$ while it satisfies $d_i\leq4$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: This would be pretty easy to formulate as an integer programming problem. Are you willing to take that approach? If so I can suggest a formulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to find an optimal solution with any approach. It would be great if you give me any hint or new formulation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a formulation using integer programming (IP).

**Sets and Parameters:**

- $G$ = set of green vertices
- $B$ = set of blue vertices
- $N$ = set of all vertices ($=G\cup B$)
- $a_{kn} = 1$ if black vertex $k$ ($k\in\{1,2\}$) in the original network, $0$ otherwise

**Decision Variables:**

- $x_n = 1$ if we remove vertex $n\in N$, $0$ otherwise
- $y = $ minimum (over {blue,green}) number of vertices in each group

**Formulation:**

$$\begin{alignat}{2}
\text{maximize} \quad & y && \\
\text{subject to} \quad & y \le \sum_{b\in B} (1-x_b) \\
& y \le \sum_{g\in G} (1-x_g) \\
& \sum_{n \in N} a_{kn}(1-x_n) \le 4 &\quad& \forall k\in \{1,2\} \\
& x_n \in \{0,1\} && \forall n\in N
\end{alignat}$$

The objective function maximizes the minimum number of vertices in each group (what you called $min(d_B,d_G)$ in your question). The first two constraints say that $y$ (the minimum) must be less than or equal to each of the vertex sets, after removals. (Note that $1-x_b$ and $1-x_g$ equal 1 if we don't remove the node and 0 if we do.) The third constraint says that for each black vertex $k$, the total number of edges that are connected to $k$ ($a_{kn}=1$) and are attached to a vertex that has not been removed ($1-x_n$) must be less than or equal to 4.

Now you can code this in your modeling language of choice and solve it with any IP solver.

Comment: Thanks a lot Larry.

Answer (score 1):

**Definitions:**

- $d_1^s = d_{1B}^s +  d_{1G}^s$ the number of single edges to vertex 1: $d_{1B}$ and $d_{1G}$ are the number of single edges blue and green to vertex 1, respectively.
- $d_2^s= d_{2B}^s + d_{2G}^s$ the number of single edges to vertex 2.
- $d^d= d_{B}^d + d_{G}^d$ the number of double edges.

Now,

- The number of vertexs blue and green will be:
  $$N_B = d_{1B}^s + d_{2B}^s + d_{B}^d$$
  $$N_G = d_{1G}^s + d_{2G}^s + d_{G}^d$$
- The number of edges to vertexs 1 and 2 will be:
  $$d_1 = d_1^s + d^d = d_{1B}^s + d_{1G}^s + d_{B}^d + d_{G}^d$$
  $$d_2 = d_2^s + d^d = d_{2B}^s + d_{2G}^s + d_{B}^d + d_{G}^d$$

We can see:
$$ N_B + N_G = d_1 + d_2 - d^d $$

**Aims:**

We are asked for an algorithm to get $d_1 \leq 4$ and $d_2 \leq 4$ as well as $N_B$ and $N_G$ subject to being the maximum value of $\text{min} (N_B, N_G)$.

We consider the case $d_1 = 4$ and $d_2 = 4$ and look for the maximum value of $\text{min} (N_B, N_G)$ subject to $ N_B + N_G = 8 - d^d $. The solution to this optimization problem is $N_B = N_G = \frac{8 - d^d}{2}$, but because they are integers, sometimes this is not possible, and our aim is to get:
$$N_B = 4-\left.\frac{ d^d}{2}\right|_{\mathcal{Z}_{\text{sgn}(d_G^d-d_B^d)}}$$
$$N_G = 4-\left.\frac{d^d}{2}\right|_{\mathcal{Z}_{\text{sgn}(d_B^d-d_G^d)}}$$
where $x|_{\mathcal{Z}_+}$ is rounding the real $x$ to the next integer and $x|_{\mathcal{Z}_-}$ is rounding the real $x$ to the previous integer. We introduce this condition because if $d_G^d-d_B^d > 0$ sometimes it will be the only option to get $N_G = N_B + 1$ (for example if $d_G^b = 3$ and $d_B^b = 0$, we can only get $N_G = 3$ and $N_B = 2$).

**Algorithm:**

All this means that first, we will try to remove all possible double edges, because they decrease the final $N_B$ and $N_G$ which decrease $\text{min} (N_B, N_G)$. But also, keeping a similar number of $d_G^d \sim d_B^d$, because if we have only $4$ double edges of the same color, the other colour will have $0$ vertices at the end and $\text{min} (N_B, N_G) = 0$. I leave the practical implementation for you to think. Keep in mind also the cases when you are starting already with $d_1 + d_2 <8$, which would change the aiming condition.

Comment: I really appreciate your insightful comments and approach. The approach you described will definitely reach a feasible solution. So, the question will be about the optimality. How can I show that the minimum number of remaining coloured vertices (minimum over colours) are maximized? Do you have any hint for me? Once again, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @zstr I don't competely understand what do you want to optimize, can you clarify it to me a little bit? *Minimum number of remaining coloured vertices* means that you want to be left with the minimum number of coloured vertices with the minimum steps? In that case you might be interested in removing first all double vertices (exchange steps $2a$ and $2b$).

Comment: You are right. Let me explain the objective function. Assume $N_G$ and $N_B$ as the number of green circles and blue squares, respectively. I want to find a sub-graph after elimination in which $d_1\leq 4$, $d_2\leq 4$ while this sub-graph has the maximum value of $min(N_G,N_B)$ among all possible solutions. So, objective function is $maximize\:min(N_G,N_B)$ and constraints are $d_1\leq 4$ and $d_2\leq 4$.

Comment: @zstr I made an edit after understanding the optimisation condition. I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is actually very helpful. I definitely try to generalize your algorithm. I really appreciate it.